# Reading Email from Inbox c#

Tags: c#, imap, pop3, mail-server

I want to read Emails form only inbox not from sent box. I am using pop3client STAT Command to read a email and it is reading both inbox and sent box emails. Is it possible to read only inbox emails ?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Show your work..

Answer (score 1):

POP3 does not support folder management. This came way later than POP3

See [Specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html)

> IMAP, such as polling an existing connection for newly arrived
>   messages and supporting multiple folders on the server, are not
>   present in POP3.

Some mail servers can be configured to provide access to IMAP folders through POP3. This functionality is uncommon so you should refer your mail server documentation on this matter. Usually, if the server supports accessing multiple folders through POP3, selecting a folder is performed on the login stage:

```
Pop3 pop = new Pop3();
pop.Connect("mail.domain.com");
pop.Login("inbox#jdoe", "secret");
```

Notice that Some servers may require you to specify folder name AFTER login name, or use another character (not '#') as a separator. This all depends on the server configuration.

In order to access these directly without beeing dependent on the server configurationyou will need to use IMAP, take a look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/emails-using-IMAP-53046bc2).